# find exact match of letters using grep

Tags: regex

I got a one little problem. I have few files:

```
hello-1.c
hello-1.o
hello-2..c
hello-2.o
hello-3.c
Makefile
testorder
```

and using grep I want to obtain only files which contain one letter "e".

When I try this way:

```
ls | grep "e\{1\}
```

it still give me i.e `Makefile`. For any reply thanks in   advance.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are listed in a file, you can use `grep "^[^e]*e[^e]*$"`. This will hit instances that start with zero or more non-e characters, have an e in them, and end with zero or more non-e characters.

If the files are in a directory, you should use `find . -regex '^[^e]*e[^e]*$'`

Comment: Quick question: are the filenames in a file themselves? If not, `cd` into the directory with the files and try this: `find . -regex '[^e]*e[^e]*'`

Comment: All files are in directory. Second method with 'find' work..but I complain on it..isn't there any straightforward way to achieve it?

Comment: No. For what you are trying to do, find is the only solution.  Technically, you could pipe the output of find into grep, but there's no point.

Comment: This *is* a general way to do that.  My regex will work if it starts or ends with e.  the `*` next to the `[^e]` means 0 or more.  In other words, this will hit on `e`, `fie`, but not `eep` or `tiered`.